# Quick smoke noise in blender 2.82

Tags: smoke-simulation

I followed many tutorials to get the best result of a cloud of smoke on a sphere following a curve. In blender 2.82 I can not find the "high resolution" function. My problem is that the other objects have best quality but the smoke has a low quality. I add "resolution division" until 500 but it has not improved much beyond asking for a lot of resources. Also the noise has not improved the quality. In the image you can see the difference between smoke and object. I wish they both had the same quality.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: What's the size of your render (width x height)? and what's the size of this smoke object? I can't really see any objects in the screenshot

Comment: @Luciano The size of render camera is 3840px x 2160px. The object is 3017x8020mm and the smoke object size is 2000x2000mm